# General compare of 2 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of numbers, i want a generic formula to subtract the current cell from the previous cell.

```
A1 123
A2 234
A3 345
A5 456
A6 567
```

I want a generic function so that i can for example compare A6 with the previous cell (A5) without have to do something like this all the time:

```
=SUM(A6-A5)
```

Is there a way to do this with Excel?

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: Hopefully better explains it now

Comment: You can just do `=A6-A5` if you only have two cells

Comment: That was just an example, i want a generic function to compare current cell with previous cell.  I need to replicate it many times and therefore dont want to do it the laborious way

Comment: but what do mean by compare? calculate a value some where, color a cell if it is lower or higher than its predecessor etc?

Comment: do you mean you want to drag and drop the formula and getting the fomula changed? see http://superuser.com/questions/305651/excel-formula-using-relative-row-and-constant-value

Answer (score 0):

in VBA you could program a public accessible function with relative cell directive to the selected cell.

for making it easy you could first record a macro for the right vba commands, and than change the macro to your specific needs and make it publicly accessible.

somthing like this:

```
Public Function funtionname()
Dim val1, val2 As Integer
    val1 = ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value
    val2 = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    functionname = val1 + val2
End Function
```

in excel in the specific cell you add your own function like "=functionname()"

Comment: It's bad practice to have a UDF reference another cell internally. References to other cells should be passed in as parameters instead.

Comment: you are right that is is bad practice, but bad practice seems to be the only answer to this question as far as I understand the question itself.